# Can you check if a dat.gui interface is being interacted with?

Tags: javascript, dat.gui

I was wondering if you could check if a dat.gui interface is being interacted with. I have a hold and drag behaviour in my code that let's me rotate the camera. But there is a situation where I try to change a value in my interface by holding and dragging a sidebar and the camera rotates too.

[image]

Is there any way to do a check on that so it doesn't rotate on that situation?

You can try the program [here](https://the-kob.github.io/LightStudioCGI/).

Edit: there's also a bunch of other weirdness when dragging and holding with a cursor over the interface, all of it could be gone if I could check if I was interacting with the interface.